# pushViewController not working in iOS 5 but working fine in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller that pushes a new viewcontroller. It is working fine in iOS6, but not working fine in iOS5. Btw, I am running on iPhone Simulator.

My code looks like this:

```
myViewController *newView = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController"
                                                                          bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

Tried this as well:

```
myViewController *newView = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController"
                                                                          bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

Not working.

Tried the solution in this: [pushViewController Not Working on iOS 5 (OK on iOS 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714997/pushviewcontroller-not-working-on-ios-5-ok-on-ios-6).

Not showing the new view controller either, need some guidance on this. Thanks.

Comment: check if your navigationController is not nil when on Ios 5.

Comment: it is not nil. Just checked...

Comment: Not working fine in iOS5 means? wether it is crashing??

Comment: not crashing.. just not going to the new viewcontroller...

Comment: **Once just have a look at to this answer** 


http://stackoverflow.com/a/13716359/1443976

Comment: already tried that...

Comment: Okay.. just have a break point at myViewController's viewDidLoad and let me know whether it is coming to there or not ??

Comment: no going into the viewDidLoad...

Comment: @VenkatManoharPerepa Any idea?

Comment: Okay.... did you declare navigationController in your appDelegate ??

Comment: yes.. I declared it in my appDelegate...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29720/discussion-between-lakesh-and-venkat-manohar-perepa)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this line just to test if there is some problem with your nib file or not.

```
 myViewController *newView = [[myViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

In `- (void)viewDidLoad` write `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

just to test whether or not your viewcontroller is pushing. 
If you are able to push your View Controller using this method. Then there might be some issue with your nib file.

Comment: not able to push the view controller at all.. not even going into next viewcontroller...

Answer (score 1):

Do you using storyboard or xib? If you are using storyboard this can help you [initwithnibname method in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973054/initwithnibname-method-in-storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

I has similar issue. Got it solved by removing 'AutoLayout' constraint inside View to be Pushed.![image: Just uncheck Autolayout]